# Private struct as a return type of a public method

Tags: c#, class, struct

I'm building a class which goal is to read, process and output MNIST data.

For the purpose of cleaniness, i decided i would want the user to be able to access only the data reading method, `Readfile()`.

I tried to figure out the best way to return the data, and have fiddled with:

1. **Tuples**, but as you can judge from the code it got incredibly ugly and barely readable.
2. **ExpandoObjects**
3. **Structs** (as in code below)

As for now, I've been wondering wether it's possible to return a private struct in a public method, and maybe catch it in a `var` type to further process it like an object.

All I really want to achieve is to return an object that cannot be accessed directly by calling the `MNISTReader` class.

Code:

```
abstract class MNISTReader
{
    // Define structs that hold our data.
    public struct DataPair
    {
        List<byte> Labels { get; set; }
        List<Matrix<byte>> Images { get; set; }

        public DataPair(List<byte> labels, List<Matrix<byte>> images)
        {
            this.Labels = labels;
            this.Images = images;
        }
    }

    public struct Data
    {
        DataPair Train { get; set; }
        DataPair Validation { get; set; }
        DataPair Test { get; set; }

        public Data(DataPair train, DataPair validation, DataPair test)
        {
            this.Train = train;
            this.Validation = validation;
            this.Test = test;
        }
    }

    // Method for reading the files and obtaining data.
    public static Data ReadFile()
    {

        // IMAGE PROCESSING (CUT OUT)

        DataPair train = new DataPair(trainLabels, trainImages);
        DataPair validation = new DataPair(validationLabels, validationImages);
        DataPair test = new DataPair(testLabels, testImages);

        return new Data(train, validation, test);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"catch it in a var type"` - Not sure what that even means.  But essentially if code outside of that class needs to understand the return type, then that type needs to be visible to that code.  So if the method which returns a `struct` is `public`, that `struct` must also be `public`.  Otherwise consuming code wouldn't be able to understand the return type.

Comment: Yeah I do know that, i was just wondering if there was another way to do that. Could you maybe suggest other ways to return data following the guidelines I gave in the question?

Comment: I still don't follow the why - why would you want to return a type that no consumer knows about? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @KamilSolecki: What guidelines?  You have a method which returns a value.  I don't really see the problem here.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Nobody mention `interface` yet. Public methods may return public `IData` type instead of private `Data` type as result. In `IData` you define as public only what you want to be visible to the caller. In your case however it seems you want to receive result, which is not used by caller at all, but (correct me if I am wrong) passed to another method, etc. Then `object` is the right type to return. Thought I would rethink architecture (why another method can't obtain strong typed result by himself?).

Comment: The architecture is entirely flexible by now, this is only what i've come to as the latest (and to provide insight into what im working with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method returns a type, then that type needs to be "as visible" as the method itself.

This is simply because the consuming code needs to be able to understand the object being returned.  Whether it's a class or struct makes no difference in this regard.  C# is a statically typed language and so the compiler needs to be able to guarantee that any code which consumes that method will be aware of the return type.

It's very common for libraries to "hide" internal types and simply expose some structs/DTOs/etc. publicly for consumers of the library to interact with it.  Just keep your `struct` public so consumers of the `public` method will be able to understand it.

If you don't want that particular type to be visible outside of the class/library/etc., create another type for the purpose of consuming code to receive the data.  A simple DTO with no functionality on it (which, well, is what you already have in the posted code really) would do the job nicely.

Comment: I've just read a little about DTO's. So I just make another class that simply holds values and push values in my reader through it, then when using in a program read them with the DTO and assign them to proper value holders?

Comment: @KamilSolecki: A DTO is basically just a class or struct which has no functionality and exists just to hold data.  They're often useful at service boundaries when serializing data.  A class library interface boundary can provide the same semantics and be treated as a service.  I suppose the example in the question is a bit more contrived and the objects you currently have do contain more functionality that you want to hide?  Otherwise, the objects you currently have appear to already be DTOs.

Comment: They have no extra functionality, thats what I made to hold / transfer values. Good to know it has a name, though :)
So should I leave them be as they are, without worrying that user accesses their properties?
Not that it is a concern, I just wanted everything to be as clean as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return a private type from a public function.  The only way to do that is to make the return type of your public function `object`, since all types derive from it, or `dynamic`, which defers all type checking and method binding to run-time.  However, some drawbacks if either choice are:

- The caller has no idea what type will be returned, what properties it has, etc
- Any coding errors (typos, etc) will not be discovered until run-time

> All I really want to achieve is to return an object that cannot be accessed directly by calling the MNISTReader class.

One thing you can do is make the constructor *internal*, that way only the assembly it's in can *create* instances. But the type needs to be `public` if you want clients to be able to use its properties or methods.

I would also note that nothing in your requirements indicates that `DataPair` should be a struct.  The choice to make something a `struct` are more about its value-type semantics than its accessibility.